# non-SSL web service on SSL-enabled Tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, ssl, https

I currently have Tomcat 7 server running a web service.
I've enabled 2-way SSL in server.xml

```
<Connector port="8443"
maxThreads="500"
scheme="https"
secure="true"
SSLEnabled="true"
keystoreFile="tomcat_keystore.jks"
keystorePass="*******"
truststoreFile="tomcat_truststore.jks"
truststorePass="*****"
clientAuth="true"
keyAlias="tomcat"
redirectPort="8080"
sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

The direct connection to HTTPS web service works fine.
But when I call it through the Load Balancer, it is failing because current health check fails (so it thinks that web service is down).
If this health check passes, the Load balancer will simply forward the request to Tomcat server.
Current health check is just calling HTTPS GET method and expects a 200 OK.

I know I can get this resolved by installing the certs on the Load balancer but I don't want to do that because I just need to verify:
    1) If the box is up and running
    2) if the tomcat server is up and running

Is it possible to have another web service running at the same time on the same tomcat server which can be called by HTTP GET (no SSL)? which I can add it in the Load Balancer health check?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. But **not on same port**.

You have to configure another connector.

Comment: If I add another connector in server.xml for port 8080, how will tomcat know which web service it is for? because I want one of the web service to be SSL and the new one (for Load balancer) to be non-SSL

Comment: `SSLEnabled="true"` property tells will it use SSL or not. Configure proper value for your connector.

Comment: thanks @talex i just had to specify another Connector on a different port.